# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Auth\GenericUser::hasFriendRequestPending()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

i have this error i use laravel 5.3 Call to undefined method Illuminate\Auth\GenericUser::hasFriendRequestPending() can anyone help me please ?!!

User Model

```
     public function friendsOfMine()
      {
       return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'friends' , 'user_id' , 'friend_id');
      }
      public function friendOf(){
       return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'friends' , 'friend_id' , 'user_id' );
      }
     public function friendRequestsPending()
      {
       return $this->friendOf()->wherePivot('accepted' , false)->get();
      }
     public function hasFriendRequestPending(User $user)
     {
     return (bool) $this->friendRequestsPending()->where('id' , $user->id)->count();
     }
```

in view

```
                    <h4>Friend Requests</h4>
                    @if (Auth::user()->hasFriendRequestPending($user))
                          <p>Waiting For {{$user->username}} To Accept Your Request. </p>

                    @endif
```

auth.php

```
      'providers' => [
        'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
],
```

Comment: You have a little typo in your question, I think. You wrote `hasFriendRequestsPending` in your error message, while the rest of your code is `hasFriendRequestPending`, so it got me confused, that's all.

Comment: that's my error
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Auth\GenericUser::hasFriendRequestsPending()

Comment: I edited my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Your error is that the method `hasFriendRequestsPending()` is not defined.
But the name of your function is actually `hasFriendRequestPending()`.

Try to find where you call for `hasFriendRequestsPending()` and change it to `hasFriendRequestPending()`.

You can also check if in your config/auth.php, you set the correct provider:

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
    ],
```

Comment: can you explain more please ?

Comment: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Auth\GenericUser::hasFriendRequestPending()

Comment: Edited with a new lead, can you check?

Comment: I really don't know then, sorry. Please edit your initial question with more infos, more code, more config.